# How to install Odoo POSBox on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, odoo

I'm trying to install **Odoo POSBox** on a **Raspberry Pi**, can you help me please how to do this. I have read some tutorials on the internet but nothing works.

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error during installation ?

Comment: thank you @KevalMehta everything is okey now the probleme was :
the access point prevent file printing that's why the ticket doesn't come out from the printer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked these references?

- [**Step By Step Setup Guide**](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/9.0//point_of_sale/overview/setup.html)
- [**POSBOX Image Repositories**](https://nightly.odoo.com/trunk/posbox/)

### Update - Copied information from the link:

> ### Step By Step Setup Guide
>
> Extra dependencies
>
> Because Odoo runs on Python 2, you need to check which version of pip
>   you need to use.
>
> ```
> # pip --version
> ```
>
> If it returns something like::
>
> ```
> pip 1.5.6 from /usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/pip-1.5.6-py3.3.egg (python 3.3)
> ```
>
> You need to try pip2 instead. If it returns something like:
>       pip 1.4.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
>   You can use pip.
>   The driver modules requires the installation of new python modules:
>       # pip install pyserial
>       # pip install pyusb==1.0.0b1
>       # pip install qrcode
>
> **Access Rights**
>
> The drivers need raw access to the printer and barcode scanner
>   devices. Doing so requires a bit system administration. First we are
>   going to create a group that has access to USB devices
>
> ```
> # groupadd usbusers
> ```
>
> Then we add the user who will run the OpenERP server to `usbusers`
>
> ```
> # usermod -a -G usbusers USERNAME
> ```
>
> Then we need to create a udev rule that will automatically allow
>   members of `usbusers` to access raw USB devices. To do so create a
>   file called `99-usbusers.rules` in the `/etc/udev/rules.d/`
>   directory with the following content::
>
> ```
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", GROUP="usbusers", MODE="0660"
> SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", GROUP="usbusers", MODE="0660"
> ```
>
> Then you need to reboot your machine.
>
> **Start the local Odoo instance**
>
> We must launch the Odoo server with the correct settings
>
> ```
>  $ ./odoo.py --load=web,hw_proxy,hw_posbox_homepage,hw_posbox_upgrade,hw_scale,hw_scanner,hw_escpos
> ```
>
> **Test the instance**
>
> Plug all your hardware to your machine's USB ports, and go to
>   `http://localhost:8069/hw_proxy/status` refresh the page a few times
>   and see if all your devices are indicated as *Connected*. Possible
>   source of errors are: The paths on the distribution differ from the
>   paths expected by the drivers, another process has grabbed exclusive
>   access to the devices, the udev rules do not apply or a superseded by
>   others.
>
> **Automatically start Odoo**
>
> You must now make sure that this Odoo install is automatically started
>   after boot. There are various ways to do so, and how to do it depends
>   on your particular setup. Using the init system provided by your
>   distribution is probably the easiest way to accomplish this.
>
> **Setup the Point of Sale**
>
> The IP address field in the POS configuration must be either
>   `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` if you're running the created Odoo
>   server on the machine that you'll use as the Point of Sale device. You
>   can also leave it empty.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Sure, I have just copied the answer from the documentation. @quentin